# In what languages, associative arrays are implemented using redblack tree instead of hashtable?

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, hashtable

In wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree#Applications_and_related_data_structures

> red-black tree is a type of
>   self-balancing binary search tree, a
>   data structure used in computing
>   science, typically used to implement
>   associative arrays.

Anyone know a language implemented associative array using redblack tree?

Comment: Just throwing this out there: not every language guarantees the implementation method of containers; some of them only guarantee the run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ [std::map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(C%2B%2B)) is often implemented as red-black tree. It's the basic associative array. The other one (new) is std::unordered_map and is in fact a hash-map.

Answer (score 4):

[java.util.TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is an implementation of a red-black tree in Java.

Answer (score 2):

In **C#** [**SortedDictionary**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) is implemented as Red-Black tree, while [**Dictionary**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) uses hashtable and [**SortedList**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) is basically list with binary search for keys lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a *red-black* tree, but [Haskell's Data.Map](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/containers-0.3.0.0/Data-Map.html) is a balanced binary tree:

> The implementation of Map is based on size balanced binary trees (or trees of bounded balance) as described by:
>
> - Stephen Adams, "Efficient sets: a balancing act", Journal of Functional Programming 3(4):553-562, October 1993, [http://www.swiss.ai.mit.edu/~adams/BB/](http://www.swiss.ai.mit.edu/%7Eadams/BB/).
> - J. Nievergelt and E.M. Reingold, "Binary search trees of bounded balance", SIAM journal of computing 2(1), March 1973.

Ocaml has both a mapping type ontop of [hashtables](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html) and a [binary trees](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html).

Comment: This user died.

Answer (score 1):

Scala's [`scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/TreeMap.html) is implemented with a Red-Black tree.